# Is there a way to add a new CIDR to authorized networks for cluster master access in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

When creating a new cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine with the `gcloud container clusters create` command, one can specify a list of authorized networks that can access the master using the `--master-authorized-networks` flag. That list can be updated by passing a list of new authorized networks to the `--master-authorized-networks` flag in a `gcloud container clusters update` command. 
This method apparently overrides the initial list of authorized networks with the new one. 
I'd like to know if there is a way to simply add a new authorized network(or an ip address) to the existing ones

Answer (score 0):

If you do it through the GUI is additive, though when you the the SDK or the API, you are defining the list of authorized networks. So programmatically, no. Sounds like a good feature request though

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up writing a script that first retrieves the initial list of authorized networks, converts it to a comma separated string, then appends the new one and updates the cluster with it